Disable hyperlink warnings in Office For Solidworks PDM
We are getting security notices about conisio://PDM VAULT being an unsafe location.
I've added conisio://PDM VAULT to Trusted Locations, but it still gives me the security notice.
Has anyone found how to properly set this?
Added conisio://PDM VAULT to Trusted Locations expecting it to stop the messages.
Security notices still appear.
